# Why we use "to this" instead of only "this"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, phrase-meaning

Why do we use "to this" when we say something like "*if you are listening to this*" and not just "this" without "to"? For example "to" is not used when we say "*if you are reading this*".

Comment: Because some English verbs require a preposition when they have an object (listen to, look at, pick up) and some don't.

Answer (score 1):

It is (or should be) part of the dictionary definition of each verb (and many adjectives and nouns) what kinds of object or complement they take.

It happens that *hear* takes a direction object:

> I heard him.

but *listen* requires a "to" object:

> I listened to him.

Similarly, *see* takes a direct object:

> Did you see the show?

and *watch* also takes a direct object:

> Did you watch the show?

but *look* does not, and requires an "at" object:

> Did you look at the book?

There's no rule or logic to this: it's just the way English happens to work at this stage in its history.